# FTP file upload using perl from local system

Tags: perl, ftp

**Requirement:**

I want to create a script that will upload files from local system to FTP server in using perl.

**Sample Code:**

```
use Net::FTP;
    $ftp = Net::FTP->new("some.host.name", Debug => 0)
      or die "Cannot connect to some.host.name: $@";
    $ftp->login("anonymous",'-anonymous@')
      or die "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;
    $ftp->cwd("/pub")
      or die "Cannot change working directory ", $ftp->message;
    $ftp->get("that.file")
      or die "get failed ", $ftp->message;
    $ftp->quit;
```

P.S: Newbie in Perl.

Comment: Define "not working". What does it do? What error messages are reported?

Comment: it is not posting the any files

Comment: What *is* it doing? What error messages are reported? What makes you think it should "post" files (whatever you mean by that)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this code this is working fine for me

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;

my ($ftp, $host, $user, $pass, $dir, $fpath);

$host = "";
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$dir = "";

$fpath = "";

$ftp = Net::FTP->new($host, Debug => 0);
$ftp->login($user, $pass) || die $ftp->message;
$ftp->cwd($dir);
$ftp->put($fpath) || die $ftp->message;
$ftp->quit;

print $ftp->message;
```

Comment: what is the problem in my code will u explain why u have downvoted it

Comment: file path i have to pass is relative or absolute

Comment: pass the complete path from both locations

Comment: this serves only uploading to FTP server. How about **downloading the same file** now? Another requirement is now I want to *repeat* this upload/download process **inside a loop.** How to achieve it?

Comment: where do the downloaded files gets saved?

Comment: set your location where you want

Comment: I added $sock->recv("/home/rancore/arka/10mega.test") or die $ftp->message; and installed the module **IO:Socket:Socks:Wrapper**. It did not work.

Comment: Gaurav - Can you look into this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822411/automate-ftp-upload-download-using-perl-and-store-the-throughput-stats-in-exce